# Display 100% Child Width when Parent is only 50%

Tags: css

Is there anyway to make a a child element 100% width of the screen while it's parent is only 50%?

For example, I need to make the black footer for this site extend the full width of the screen while maintaining the integrity of the rest of the site. msdnw.com/

I created my custom div of #blackback and have tried various ways to make it work and just can't. Any ideas? P.S. Yes I've already tried placing the div below the footer code as apposed to wrapping the footer. But perhaps the code I was using was not working how I needed.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `#blackback` css to:

```css
#blackback {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

should do it.

Comment: Welcome.  You may want to ditch the height attribute.  At an extreme zoomed out scale, you have elements that pop outside of the footer div.

Answer (score 0):

You want to go and use Absolute positioning:

```css
.child {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

hope that helps